# How do i make my counter value remain, when i refresh the page with localStorage in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

i have tried all i could, i could get a solution, i need  my count value to remain, even if i refresh my page. for example if my count is up to 3, and when i refresh my browser, the 3 should remain and not start from zero.

can i get any help?? i am currently learning localstorage

here is the code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function LocalStorageSetting() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  };

  localStorage.setItem("count", count);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Increase</button>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read it when you set the initial value

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(+(localStorage.count || 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

@epascarello's answer works. You could also use the setCount function you created.

```
const storageCount = Number(localStorage.getItem("count")) ?? 0;
const [count, setCount] = useState(storageCount);
```

Also note that `localStorage` stores string key/value pairs. `count` should have something like `.toString()` on the end when adding it as the value. So use `localStorage.setItem("count", count.toString())`.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your state using the value stored in Local Storage, this way, the value count will init by LS value. Keep in mind that Local Storage saves your value as `string`, so you need to parse the value before init to be sure that your value will be typed as Number

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(Number(localStorage.count || 0));
```

Something I like to do it keep the value save in the save function that changed the value, keeping the value changes in a single function.

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  localStorage.setItem("count", count);
};
```